# Updated Balance Against Every Month SQL

Tags: sql, date-range

I'm using the below query to get the updated balance of every customer against a month. The Given date range is only for one month, but now I need to pull the latest balances against everyone in the given date range. The query is below for your reference.

```
SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT id,
                        date_1,
                        balance,
                        Row_number()
                          OVER (
                            partition BY id
                            ORDER BY date_1 DESC) AS RN
                 FROM   customer
             WHERE  date_1 BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-30'
                
                ) sub
         WHERE  rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing Partition By in the Row_number() window function.

```
SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT id,
                        date_1,
                        balance,
                        Row_number()
                          OVER (ORDER BY date_1 DESC) AS RN
                 FROM   customer
             WHERE  date_1 BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-30'
                
                ) sub
         WHERE  rn = 1
```